# How to align array inside align?

Tags: align, arrays

I wrote an array environment inside align. As array have a blank space around it, I cant align it properly.

I'm using array{l}, because I do want elements on the left inside array.

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
a=&a
\\
a=&\begin{array}{l}
bb
\\
ccc
\end{array}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One suggestion: could you perhaps change the title of your question to `How to align entries of a matrix`? That way it may get more attention, and I do not think that the problem is related to the math environment `align`. But this is all up to you.

Comment: Try `\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I think to understand what you want: the `matrix*` environment from the `mathtools` package.

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
a&=aaaa
\\
a&=\begin{matrix*}[l]
bbb
\\
cc
\end{matrix*}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didnt explain well enough and my example was poor. It should be left aligned and elements have different size. Matrix are centered.

Comment: I updated my question. Maybe I have a solution with \hspace[-5pt] but I dont know if it is a general solution

Comment: Your matrix is centered. as you see in my question, I use array{l}. I made an answer myself using hspace, I just dont know if it is a general solution.

Comment: Now you made it general. I have already seen solutions like yours on pmatrix, but it didnt work on matrix. I didnt know things changed on matrix* environment.

Comment: The spacing around = is wrong. It should be `&=`

Comment: @egreg I changed it. (But I also don't think this was what the the question was about.)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the padding.

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
a&=a
\\
a&=\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
bb
\\
ccc
\end{array}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

For correct spacing around the = sign, the `&` should go in front of it.